# laravel 5 can GET routes, but not POST

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

going through the tutorial on Laravel 5 here:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart

Now, when it comes to trying to post form data to /task I get an error...

```
Not Found
The requested URL /task was not found on this server.
```

Worse, if I set up a route to GET /task and echo out something simple - this works. Is there something I am missing for a POST, please?

Here is my full route file:

```
<?php

use App\Task;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/**
 * Display All Tasks
 */
Route::get('/', function () {
    $tasks = Task::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();

    return view('tasks', [
        'tasks' => $tasks
    ]);
});

/**
 * Add A New Task
 */
Route::post('/task', function (Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        //return redirect('/')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }

    $task = new Task;
    $task->name = $request->name;
    $task->save();

    //return redirect('/');
});

/**
 * Delete An Existing Task
 */
Route::delete('/task/{id}', function ($id) {
    Task::findOrFail($id)->delete();

    return redirect('/');
});


Route::get('/task', function() {
    echo 'ds';
});
```

Thanks folks.

DS

edit.... here is my form code I am posting with

```
@extends('layouts.scaffold')

@section('main')

    <!-- Create Task Form... -->
    <form action="/task" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <!-- Task Name -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="task" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Task</label>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="task-name" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Add Task Button -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Task
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <!-- Current Tasks -->
    @if (count($tasks) > 0)
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Current Tasks
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-striped task-table">

                    <!-- Table Headings -->
                    <thead>
                        <th>Task</th>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    </thead>

                    <!-- Table Body -->
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach ($tasks as $task)
                            <tr>
                                <!-- Task Name -->
                                <td class="table-text">
                                    <div>{{ $task->name }}</div>
                                </td>

                                <!-- Delete Button -->
                                <td>
                                    <form action="/task/{{ $task->id }}" method="POST">
                                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

                                        <button>Delete Task</button>
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
@endsection
```

Comment: How are you accessing the `post` route. Are you using a form with the `method` set to `post`?

Comment: How can you access your POST route?

Comment: Are you trying via postman client or related to access your POST or via form  ?

Comment: I am posting via a form. i have edited my question to include the form code. thanks so much

Comment: If you change `action="/task"` to `action="{{ url("/task") }}"` does it work?

Comment: @TimLewis - absolutely it does! thanks so much. i wonder should the tutorial on the site be updated. works great now. thanks again.

Comment: No problem, I'll write a quick answer explaining the logic, so other users can benefit from it. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason Laravel couldn't resolve the `POST` route is that `/task` is the route's name, and not the complete address. Instead of looking for `http://localhost/project/task`, it was just looking for `/task`, which isn't a valid address. The solution is to use Laravel 5's `url()` helper method to specify the `action` of the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url("/task") }}">...</form>
<!-- {{ ... }} is .blade syntax for <?php ... ?> -->
```

Also, note the the `GET` routes were working as `redirect("/")` functions similarly to `url("/")`